# How to code a tree kind of menu in wicket framework

Tags: menu, wicket

I am new to Apache wicket framework I need to construct a  menu as mentioned below,

```
-book1
  -SubMenu1
  -SubMenu2
  -SubMenu3
  -SubMenu4
-book2
  -SubMenu1
  -SubMenu2
  -SubMenu3
  -SubMenu4
+book3
+book4
```

On-click of +Menu i have to open sub menu's,So it kind of books and pages(sub menus)

is there any possibility to do it wicket framework?,
Can you please tell me  how do it ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/nested/) example

Comment: @pikand I have added the above code but the + - symbols not loaded.

Comment: <span class="minus"></span> is rendered but not enabled,So the minus symbol is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the tree by using wicket-jquery ui.

please refer http://www.jstree.com/ to your reference